# How to find dict value by Key in list

Tags: python

I have following List:

```
lst = [
    {'Title1': {'Link': 'ZbELsW_tyWA', 'Episode': 'Episode Name'}},
    {'Title2': {'Link': 'ZbELsW_tyWA', 'Episode': 'Episode Name2'}},
]
```

Now I want to search list by word *Title1*

How to get values of *Link* and *Episode* of certain key

Comment: Don't name your object `list`; that masks the built-in type.

Comment: You have four `{`s but only two `}`s, please review the data in your question. Also, if each dictionary in the list will just have done key with a dictionary value, why not have them all in one dictionary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a list comprehension to produce all matches:

```
[d[searchtitle] for d in lst if searchtitle in d]
```

where `searchtitle` contains `'Title1'`. The result is a list of matching dictionaries.

Finding the *first* match only:

```
next((d[searchtitle] for d in lst if searchtitle in d), None)
```

which returns `None` if there is no match, or a dictionary with the matching key in it.

Demo:

```
>>> lst = [
...     {'Title1': {'Link': 'ZbELsW_tyWA', 'Episode': 'Episode Name'}},
...     {'Title2': {'Link': 'ZbELsW_tyWA', 'Episode': 'Episode Name2'}},
... ]
>>> searchtitle = 'Title1'
>>> [d[searchtitle] for d in lst if searchtitle in d]
[{'Episode': 'Episode Name', 'Link': 'ZbELsW_tyWA'}]
>>> next((d[searchtitle] for d in lst if searchtitle in d), None)
{'Episode': 'Episode Name', 'Link': 'ZbELsW_tyWA'}
```

Instead of storing each title as a separate dictionary in a list, your search would be much simpler if you just stored each title as a key in *one* dictionary:

```
titles = {
    'Title1': {'Link': 'ZbELsW_tyWA', 'Episode': 'Episode Name'},
    'Title2': {'Link': 'ZbELsW_tyWA', 'Episode': 'Episode Name2'},
}
```

as now all you have to do to get the nested dictionary is directly reference the title key:

```
titles['Title1']
```

Provided your titles are unique.

Comment: Great answer!!! Love the way you have done it in a sinle line. how can I learn this??

Comment: Play loads with Python and read loads of answers on Stack Overflow?

Comment: @MartijnPieters How your list formation is different than mine?

Comment: It doesn't create a list at all; it creates a dictionary.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Pardon. I was actually answering this `Instead of storing each title as a separate dictionary in a list, your`

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
for item in lst:
    for key,value in item.iteritems():
        if key == "Title1":
            link = value["Link"]
            episode = value["Episode"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the filter function. The first argument to the function is a function which would help filter the list. The function we need here needs to check if 'Title1' exists in the dictionary. So this expression would give you your answer :

```
filter(lambda x : 'Title1' in x, lst)
```